# How to label a row of plots with the labels close to the plots?

Tags: labeling

I am running this code:

```
Plot3D[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-5, 10}] & /@ {x, y, 
   Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[x + y], Abs[x] + Abs[y]} // 
 GraphicsGrid[{#, {"x", "y", 
     "\[LeftBracketingBar]x\[RightBracketingBar]", 
     "\[LeftBracketingBar]y\[RightBracketingBar]", 
     "\[LeftBracketingBar]x+y\[RightBracketingBar]", 
     "\[LeftBracketingBar]x\[RightBracketingBar]+\[LeftBracketingBar]\
y\[RightBracketingBar]"}}] &
```

to produce this result:

[image: list of plots]

which is great. But I would like the labels to be rendered closer to the plots.  Is there some way to do that with `GraphicsGrid`?

(I don't really want to be using a `GraphicsGrid` – I actually want to be using a `GraphicsRow`, with labels below the plots.  But I can't figure out how to do that.  This is the best hack I have come up with.)

Comment: Replace `GraphicsGrid` by `Grid`?

Comment: Try `Labeled[Plot3D[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-5, 10}], TraditionalForm[#]] & /@ {x, y, Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[x + y], Abs[x] + Abs[y]}`.

Comment: I would accept either of these as a solution.  What's the protocol?  Should I convert both into a solution & accept?  Or should I just delete the question as trivial?

Comment: use `GraphicsRow[
  Labeled @@@ 
   Transpose[{#, 
     TraditionalForm /@ {x, y, Abs[x], Abs[y], Abs[x + y], 
       Abs[x] + Abs[y]}}]] &`  instead of `GraphicsGrid[...]&`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel) if you don't mind having the labels above the plots:

```
GraphicsRow[
    Map[
        Plot3D[#,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotRange->{-5,10},PlotLabel->#]&,
        {x,y,Abs[x],Abs[y],Abs[x+y],Abs[x]+Abs[y]}
    ],
    ImageSize->800
]
```

[image]

For labels below the plot you can use [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled) (as in the comments) or [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends):

```
GraphicsRow[
    Map[
        Plot3D[#,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotRange->{-5,10},PlotLegends->Placed[#,Below]]&,
        {x,y,Abs[x],Abs[y],Abs[x+y],Abs[x]+Abs[y]}
    ],
    ImageSize->800
]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Carl.  I've never seen the `Placed` directive before, it looks good to know about.